# Is boost::multiprecision::cpp_int a POD?

Tags: c++, boost, pool, multiprecision

I am intending to use classes that have `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` ([see Boost Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html)) as data members, and I am hoping to manage instances of these classes on the heap using the `boost::fast_pool_allocator` [Boost custom allocator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost/fast_pool_allocator.html).

In order for this to be safe, I need to know that `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` is a POD (or at least that it does no allocation on the heap - i.e., is purely stack-based).

Is `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` a POD?

Thanks!

Comment: Think about it for a moment, where could it possibly extend into when it grows? Also what could maybe "Determines the number of Bits to store directly within the object before resorting to dynamic memory allocation" in the documentation you have linked mean?

Comment: Yes - this is an obvious point now for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, taken from @PlasmaHH's comment, and quite obvious in retrospect, is that **no, `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int` is not a POD**.

To quote from PlasmaHH:

> Think about it for a moment, where could it possibly extend into when
>   it grows? Also what could maybe "Determines the number of Bits to
>   store directly within the object before resorting to dynamic memory
>   allocation" in the documentation you have linked mean?

Answer (score 4):

Why not write a little program to find out?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_pod<boost::multiprecision::cpp_int>::value << std::endl;
}
```

On my platform (gcc version 4.8.2) the output is 0, meaning the type isn't a POD type.

Comment: Is there a type traits class that will indicate if it allocates on the heap?  I think my POD restriction may be too restrictive.  I just need to know that it's fully stack-based.

Comment: Here's a list of the type traits that is included in C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits